# Circuit Breaker is going to OPEN state from CLOSED before the minimum number of calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I have the following config set for the circuit breaker

```
private CircuitBreakerConfig loadCircuitBreakerConfig() {

    CircuitBreakerConfig config = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
    .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofSeconds(180))
    .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(2)
    .failureRateThreshold(70)
    .slowCallRateThreshold(75)
    .slowCallDurationThreshold(Duration.ofMillis(10000))
    .slidingWindowSize(10)
    .slidingWindowType("COUNT_BASED")
    .minimumNumberOfCalls(3) // Tried with 10 also
    .build();
    
    return config;
}
```

I am creating the instance of circuit breaker as

```
circuitBreaker = CircuitBreaker.of("CircuitBreakerDemo", loadCircuitBreakerConfig());
```

Dependency added

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-circuitbreaker</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

With the minimum number of calls as 3, circuit is getting `OPEN` from `CLOSED` state after 2 failure only and if the minimum number of calls are 10 then circuit is getting `OPEN` after 5 failure. The next subsequent request are directly going in fallback scenario.
I tried with different configurations but still unable to determine what is going wrong.

As per my understanding circuit breaker will evaluate after 3 or 10 requests have been made.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is as per the configuration of circuit breaker transition from CLOSED state to OPEN state should happen after the minimum number of calls have been reached and the it should evaluate the failure. Is my understanding correct? If not can you please explain how the transition should happen from CLOSED state to OPEN state based on the above configuration.

Answer (score 1):

1. When the circuit breaker in `CLOSED` state, if any call fails the circuit breaker counts the failure and if the failure Threshold exceeds the given threshold, it transitions to `OPEN`.

a)The given failure Threshold in your configuration is 70 (when the external/remote service is considered unavailable)

- So if 2 out 3 service calls fails, 70 Threshold is reached it changes to `OPEN`.
- And if 7 out of 10 calls fails , the circuit breaker trips and transitions to `OPEN` state.

If transition to `OPEN` should be made only if 10 out 10 calls fail, threshold should be 100.

b)The given slow RATE threshold in your configuration is 75(when the external/ remote service is considered slow)

-slow call DURATION threshold (10 secs)is the amount of time a service is allowed to take to respond to the request call.

- if 10 out of 3 calls can be slow , the CB will trip for slow RATE threshold 75
- it is also possible that slow call DURATION threshold being reached, even if the slow call RATE threshold is not exceeded ,it can go to OPEN. If the external API is slow to respond it could cause your service to have slow calls and even if the slow RATE threshold is not being exceeded (75),if the slow call DURATION threshold (10 secs in your configuration)is reached it goes to OPEN.

2. When CB in OPEN state,it prevents calls to the external service, and returns error which goes to fallback method. It stays in `OPEN` state for the configured time (180 seconds in yours) then changes to `HALF OPEN`

Comment: Thank you. But if the minimum number of calls is set to 10 the transition is happening after 5 failed service calls which is still 50% of failure threshold and I cannot see any point for having sliding window size and type in config. Can you please help.

Comment: I have updated the answer. And there are two types of sliding window: Count based and Time based - Count based , the success and failure rate of calls are over fixed number of calls whereas time based window is based on calls made over fixed time period. So the sliding window size indicates the how  many calls are included in CB state analysis, the CB will look at the last 10 (size as 10)calls to determine the failure rate or slow call rate threshold being exceeded.